# Running a single spec file separately using parallel_rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, continuous-integration, parallel-testing

My requirement is to run a single rspec file at the end of the suite after all the other rspecs are run. Since the spec - specA - is changed when other tests are run in parallel with it.

I have tried --single and --isolate

> parallel_rspec -n 4 Spec/**/*.rb --isolate Spec/specA.rb

or

> parallel_rspec -n 4 Spec/**/*.rb --single Spec/specA.rb

These seem to run in the same process specified.
Or alternatively is there any way to call parallel_rspec twice without overwriting the previous exection ?
Calling parallel_rspec twice seems to give only the second run's result at the end.

Comment: Could you share a link to `parallel_rspec` gem/lib? I can't find anything that have documented `--isolate` nor `--signle` options.

Comment: Oh, I found it (https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/parallel_tests), did you try `parallel_rspec -n 4 Spec/**/*.rb --single Spec/specA.rb --isolate` ??

Comment: Yes, --single makes this specA run in a seperate thread and isolate makes sure that no other specs are using this thread for execution. But there are still other specs running in parallel.
For now , i am running them in sequence by calling parallel_rspec twice but attaching the existing run result to the previous result by not clearing the previous report.
This is only a work-around.